# Defining indexes for associated models with Thinking Sphinx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, thinking-sphinx, indexing

What is the proper way of defining indexes on associated models with following configuration?

I have model `Locality` with `lat` and `lng` attributes and associated models `Profile` and `User`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user_profile

  define_index do
    # This doesn't work :(
    has "RADIANS(user_profiles.localities.lat)", :as => :lat, :type => :float
    has "RADIANS(user_profiles.localities.lng)", :as => :lng, :type => :float
  end
end

end

class UserProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :locality
end

class Locality < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_profiles
end
```

I need to define indexes for User model so I can perform geo-searches on it.

Thank you for the answers!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is twofold:

- Thinking Sphinx doesn't know that you want to join the user_profile and locality associations.
- SQL snippets should be just that - standard SQL - so you can't chain associations within them.

The following should do the trick:

```
define_index do
  # force the join on the associations
  join user_profile.locality

  # normal SQL:
  has "RADIANS(localities.lat)", :as => :lat, :type => :float
  has "RADIANS(localities.lng)", :as => :lng, :type => :float
end
```

Claudio's point of using singular references within the SQL is not correct - within SQL, you want table names. But you do want the correct association references in the join call (hence they're singular there).

Cheers

Comment: Great, sorry for the confusion that I've created :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't really know the exact solution but:

You have a typo:

```
has_one :user_profile

define_index do
    # This doesn't work :(
    has "RADIANS(user_profiles.localities.lat)", :as => :lat, :type => :float
```

You are using "user_profiles" for the attribute, it should not be plural, try changing it to: "user_profile".

I repeat, I don't know if you can navigate through associations for this case, but if you can, this should be a typo.

You can read here for more information: http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/geosearching.html

Comment: I was trying to to reference table names. Pat's answer solves the problem, thanks anyway!